# Unable to save all the weights to .csv file

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, machine-learning, save

I'm running a simple CNN with the mnist dataset on tensorflow 2.4, and I want to save all the weights to a .csv file, the code I've tried is as following

```
for layer in model_train.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights()
    print(weights)

np.savetxt('weight.csv' , weights , fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

and

```
weight = model_train.get_weights()
np.savetxt('weight.csv' , weight , fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

and [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdlEuAW2WT0&ab_channel=AjjoAjjo) that I found

all of the result above end up saving the .csv file [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy2MT.png) that isnt saving every single weight in the layer, is there a way that can save every weight? or did I do something wrong?

My model

```
model_train = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model_train.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
              from_logits=True),
              metrics=[tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
              )

model_train.fit(
    train_images,
    train_labels,
    epochs=5,
    batch_size=480,
    validation_split=0.2
)

model_train.save('./mnist_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
weight = model_train.get_weights()
np.savetxt('weight.csv' , weight , fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: does this solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758893/converting-hdf5-to-csv-or-tsv-files ?

Comment: I've try to use the method before but I can't manage to export the .csv file

Comment: what do you mean by unable to export ? is it the format that you don't like ?

Comment: @zanga is either the csv file is empty or the data isn't what i wanted

Comment: Why a CSV file? Why not HDF5 as it is natively supported? CSV is a very bad format to save multidimensional arrays

Comment: does that really matter? of course I have my propose of converting all the weights into .csv file